# 2 minor issues with sticky header

Tags: jquery, sticky

I am using the following jquery to create a sticky header on my site (http://tinyurl.com/pmow22f):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 230){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
    $('#headerwrapper').removeClass();
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    $('#headerwrapper').addClass("headerwrapper");
  }
});
});
```

My issues are a) when scrolling down to the point of 230px where the header snaps to the top of the screen, it seems to flicker a bit and is not a very smooth transition, not sure whats causing this but if you take a look at the page you may be able to see this, and b) if the page is refreshed when half way down the screen, there is no menu at all when the page is loaded (because its at the top of the page therefore out of veiw) and doesn't appear back at the top of the screen until scrolled again, how can this be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: @dwhite.me no i'm sorry that broke my sticky header, I don't know if you are missing some brackets or something in the code but there looks like one to many closing brackets at the end, could you please confirm? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - The flicker - Seems fine on Firefox, more info needed on the issue.

2 - The doc load missing header thingy - You have this purely on scroll, so need to have this outside the scroll.

```
$(function() {
  stickyHeader();

})
$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickyHeader();
})
function stickyHeader(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 230){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
        $('#headerwrapper').removeClass();
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        $('#headerwrapper').addClass("headerwrapper");

    }
}
```

Comment: The last 2 lines needed amending from:
`    });
}`
to:
`    }
});
`

Thanks for your time.